# Zuul can't find instances on production

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have the following services registered in Eureka

[image]

The `edge-server` is a Zuul proxy configured like this:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    contacts-service:
      path: /contacts/**
      stripPrefix: true
      serviceId: contacts-service

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka:admin@127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

---

spring:
  profiles: docker

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka:admin@discovery:8761/eureka/
```

In production, everything is dockerized (don't know if it matters for this question anyway).

When I try to call the contacts service through zuul, I get this exception

```
{
  "timestamp": 1477595822755,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException",
  "message": "NUMBEROF_RETRIES_NEXTSERVER_EXCEEDED"
}
```

and the logs says

```
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM[2m2016-10-27 19:21:10.921[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Error during filtering
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PMcom.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92-internal]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92-internal]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92-internal]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PMCaused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Number of retries on next server exceeded max 1 retries, while making a call for: a0821971c1d0:contacts-service:72887579
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$4.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:350) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   ... 68 common frames omitted
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PMCaused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: a0821971c1d0
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar!/:1.1.10]
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM   ... 161 common frames omitted
10/27/2016 9:21:10 PM
```

As you can see, in the logs it shows `java.net.UnknownHostException: a0821971c1d0`. Seems like Zuul can't resolve the instace address. I can post more info if needed.

Comment: Are you using a cloud provider?

Comment: all services are dockerized o rancher, that runs on digital ocean

Comment: No experience with rancher, but you should get your service's ip from the rancher env to set `eureka.instance.hostname`, maybe something like this: https://forums.rancher.com/t/rancher-metadata-slow-to-respond-on-container-start/896

Comment: hmm, I will try but I believe if that was the case, the instances wouldn't be able to find nor connect to Eureka

Comment: If you have actuator enabled you can maybe look in the `/env` endpoint for the correct environment variable and assign it, something like this:  `eureka.instance.hostname: ${HOST}`

Comment: just added `eureka.instance.hostname: ${spring.cloud.client.ipAddress}` but same thing

Comment: You are registering with an internal address. You have to use something routable.

Comment: hmm not sure I understood. how do I do it? any sample?

Comment: Assuming `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress` is active when the `docker` profile is active than your Eureka client should be registering using the IP address of the docker container.

Comment: but since I linked the services, register using ip address or hostname shouldn't result in the same in the end?